# How do I pass parameters to a native plugin from C#(Unity)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-c++, dll, dllimport

C++ code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

class myClass
 {
  __declspec(dllexport) float addMyNum(float a)
   {
     return(a);
   }
};
```

The above code is compiled into Trail.dll and placed in the Unity project's Plugin folder.

Unity C# code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;


public class ndstryscript : MonoBehaviour {

 [DllImport("Trial", EntryPoint = "?addMyNum@myClass@@AEAAMPEAM@Z")]

 private static extern float addMyNum(float a);

 void Start ()
  {
    float b = addMyNum(20);
    Debug.Log(b);
  }

}
```

[image]

The expected output is 20 but I'm always getting 0.
Could someone help me resolve this?

Comment: Shouldn't the Entry point be EntryPoint = "addMyNum"? also since you are not renaming the function, you may as well remove it and give it a try.

Comment: Nope. The entry point is obtained from the .lib file. Not providing it gives me a `EntryPointNotFoundException`

Comment: 1. Can you show screenshot of where you put the dlll? I know you mentioned the Plugin folder but I need a screenshot. 2. Are you sure the code in C++ and C# are exactly what you're using? Nothing changed? Can you directly copy and paste and in this question to verify again?

Comment: @Programmer I have added the screenshot. Also, yes, I'm using the same code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the C++ side, you have to move the `addMyNum` function out of the `myClass` class. This should fix your function return `0` issue.

Another thing that can cause this issue is the parameter amount not matching between the C++ and C# functions. For example, when you have this on C++ side:

```
DLLExport int add(int num1, int num2){ return ...}
```

but this on the C# side:

```
[DllImport("FirstDLL")]
public static extern int add(int num1);
```

You get undefined behavior with this The result will be random because the function on the C# side has one parameter while the one from C++ has two.

---

Unrelated but using `EntryPoint = "?addMyNum@myClass@@AEAAMPEAM@Z"` really looks weird. Sometimes it's needed but other times, it's not as you will have to find the function name and match it with what you need to call on the C# side. You can just put your C++ function inside `extern "C"` and it will make sure that the compiler does not change the function name.

```
extern "C"
{
    __declspec(dllexport) float addMyNum(float a)
    {
        return(a);
    }
}
```

Then your C# side:

```
[DllImport("Trial")]
public static extern float addMyNum(float a);
```

Comment: Thanks. I will check it out and let you know. You've always been of great help.

Comment: Np. Remember to try the `extern "C"` section too if that fails to make sure you're referencing the correct function. Finally, you must **close** Unity before updating the new DLL in the Plugins folder each time or Unity will use the last one it has already loaded and even overwrite the new one once you hit play so you many see the code changes.